# A functional way of removing some columns in a 2D array

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a 2D array of the form `Seq[Array[String]]` where the first index shows the rows. The first row is always a title row. The goal is to filter out those columns that have empty title. For example if the content of the table is (3 by 3, with the first row as title):

```
 ,  t,
a,  c,  e 
b,  d,  f
```

or

```
val table = Seq(Array("", "t", ""), Array("a", "c", "e"), Array("b", "d", "f"))
```

Here the desired output, after removing empty titles:

```
t
c
d
```

`filter`ing one array is easy, but the hardness here is that, one needs to filter all the arrays based on the title row. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
val indices = table.head.zipWithIndex
                   .filter { case (t, i) => t != "" }
                   .map { case (t, i) => i }
table.map(indices collect _)
// > res: Seq[Array[String]] = List(Array(t), Array(c), Array(d))
```

Comment: you can replace the .filter(..).map(..) with a single .collect

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is using the `transpose` operator:

```
table.transpose.filterNot(_.head.isEmpty)
> Seq[Seq[String]] = List(List(t, c, d))
```